# ssl with parameters NeedClientAuth/WantClientAuth set to true fails with javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain /

Tags: ssl, jetty

I have configures the xml file as

```
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="Host">
          <SystemProperty default="0.0.0.0" name="https.host"></SystemProperty>
        </Set>
        <Set name="Port">
          <SystemProperty default="0" name="https.port"></SystemProperty>
        </Set>
        <Set name="MaxIdleTime">60000</Set>
        <Set name="Acceptors">5</Set>
        <Set name="AcceptQueueSize">100</Set>
        <Set name="StatsOn">true</Set>
        <Set name="Keystore"><SystemProperty default="." name="java.config"></SystemProperty>/mykeystore.keystore</Set>
        <Set name="KeyPassword">password</Set>
        <Set name="Password">password</Set>
        <Set name="NeedClientAuth">true</Set>
        <Set name="WantClientAuth">true</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
```

When the NeedClientAuth is set to false , I am able to open https://server.com:50881/admin/

When the NeedClientAuth is set to true as shown in the above parameters , it fails with the error

```
259498 2014-04-23 12:02:23,881 [825245763@qtp-1957835280-3] WARN  org.mortbay.log  - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
260138 2014-04-23 12:02:24,521 [825245763@qtp-1957835280-3] WARN  org.mortbay.log  - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
260689 2014-04-23 12:02:25,072 [825245763@qtp-1957835280-3] WARN  org.mortbay.log  - javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: no_certificate
```

I have added the root/intermediate/signed certificate to the server keystore 
I have also added the root/intermediate to the client IE browser

**Question
Please suggest if there is any configuration mistake 
and commands are run properly to create keystore and install the signed certificate from CA**

> Created keystore  keytool -keystore serverdns.keystore -alias server
>   -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
>
> create CSR keytool -certreq -alias server -keystore serverdns.keystore
>   -file server.csr
>
> installing signed certificate keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias
>   server -keystore serverdns.keystore -file signedcert.der.cer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that the client was unable to supply a certificate that is trusted by your server's trust store, so it didn't send a Certificate message. When the server requests the client certificate it also sends a list of acceptable signers, and the client may only send a certificate signed by one of those signers, or with a chain leading to such a certificate.

This typically happens if the client has a self-signed certificate. In this case you need to export the client's certificate from his keystore and import it into your server's truststore.

```
<Set name="NeedClientAuth">true</Set>
<Set name="WantClientAuth">true</Set>
```

It doesn't make any sense to set both of those. They are mutually exclusive. If you do that, `NeedClientAuth` probably takes precedence.

Comment: Thanks I have already included all the related certificates into the keystore. I am using keystore as truststore. Is there a way  I can debug what certificates are sent to the server without performing any code change but just modifying the jetty xml parameters

Comment: I've told you. So has the exception. *No* certificates were sent to the server. As for the rest, if you had really done everything necessary you wouldn't be asking.

Comment: I am using Internet Explorer and the certificates are installed in the intermediate and root tabs. are these tabs considered as trustore by default or I shall copy then to any other place

Comment: Thanks I have created the client keystore and certificates similar to server and added the client certificates to server keystore and after that it works fine